# how to get the base string and page no string in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

currently i am putting the full url in urlist i want the only string after pageno in the urlist and the program should go on rest as it as.

https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=**AMCR24yMNFkfoXF3wKPmGMy_wV8TJPAlxm6oWiTHGOI**

```py
urlList = ["https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=AMCR24yMNFkfoXF3wKPmGMy_wV8TJPAlxm6oWiTHGOI",
           "https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=Hgw0LYpSZdLXow1Wq84uKar1nxXbFhClXQDuAAiPDxU",
           "https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=rO5Erb90Q_P1S0fL5O6FEShlv20RBXmkHFusZogvUoo",
           "https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=jiE0kS8e-ghmlmjDMPUJm1OBCRotqJ6n7srXZN99LZc",
           "https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=MY89EG2RtzpSMlT1wjE61Cv31nAyetQ49kmXfw2AfMo",
           ]
for url in urlList:
    print('Hold on creating URL to fetch data...')
    url = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=' + str(page_no)
    print('URL created: ' + url)
    scraped_data = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    soup_data = bs(scraped_data.text, 'lxml')
    extracted_data = sou

p_data.find('div', {'id': 'pagi_content'})
```

Comment: What is the purpose of *urlList*? You're effectively using it only to control the number of iterations in your loop which seems odd. You have errors:- e.g., *sou* and *page_no* are not defined

Comment: no error coming previously page no was 1,2,3 now the website has encrypted the text

Answer (score 1):

you can split the urls on = and get the part you need:

```
for url in urls:
     print(url.split("=")[-1])

outputs:
AMCR24yMNFkfoXF3wKPmGMy_wV8TJPAlxm6oWiTHGOI
Hgw0LYpSZdLXow1Wq84uKar1nxXbFhClXQDuAAiPDxU
rO5Erb90Q_P1S0fL5O6FEShlv20RBXmkHFusZogvUoo
jiE0kS8e-ghmlmjDMPUJm1OBCRotqJ6n7srXZN99LZc
MY89EG2RtzpSMlT1wjE61Cv31nAyetQ49kmXfw2AfMo
```

if you want the page number in its own list this is how:

```
pagenumbers = [i.split("=")[-1] for i in urls]
>>> pagenumbers
['AMCR24yMNFkfoXF3wKPmGMy_wV8TJPAlxm6oWiTHGOI', 'Hgw0LYpSZdLXow1Wq84uKar1nxXbFhClXQDuAAiPDxU', 'rO5Erb90Q_P1S0fL5O6FEShlv20RBXmkHFusZogvUoo', 'jiE0kS8e-ghmlmjDMPUJm1OBCRotqJ6n7srXZN99LZc', 'MY89EG2RtzpSMlT1wjE61Cv31nAyetQ49kmXfw2AfMo']
```

there is no need to split the urls.
In your for loop you can just use the url directy since you are iterating over the full url.

```
for url in urlList:
        print('Hold on fetching data...')
        scraped_data = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        soup_data = bs(scraped_data.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: sir i want the the output in urlist and base url should be unchanged

Comment: its still unchanged, there is no mutation.
url is stil equal to `https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=AMCR24yMNFkfoXF3wKPmGMy_wV8TJPAlxm6oWiTHGOI`
at least up til the point where you are reasigning the url var.

Comment: I realy dont understand why you want to split them, in your script you are putting them back together anyways

Comment: pls tell how to add it instead of  + str(page_no)

Comment: you dont need to add it. In your urlList you already have the full url.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line after your urlList variable:

```
urlList = [x.split('=')[-1] for x in urlList]
```

Comment: pls tell how to add it instead of + str(page_no)

Comment: @DeepakJain in your for loop: url = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=' + url